# Swift Combine: `first(_ n: Int)` equivalent to RxSwift `take(_ n: Int)`?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, combine

I want an Combine operator similar to RxSwift's [`take(_ n: Int)`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Observables/Take.swift#L19-L28), I written this and it seems to be working:

## `first(_ n)` implementation

```swift
public extension Publisher where Failure == Never {
    /// Publishes the first `n` elements of a stream, then finishes.
    func first(_ numberOfElements: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {
        collect(numberOfElements)   // "Buffer"
            .first()                // "release and complete (finish)"

             // Publisher<[Output]> -> Publisher<Output>
            .map { $0.publisher }.switchToLatest()  
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

## Alternative solution?

Or can you come up with an alternative solution which is even better?

The `take` (but I named it `first`, to mirror the Combine native operator [`first`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204710-first) - *"Publishes the first element of a stream, then finishes."*) operator is really convenient when writing tests, where I want a Publisher to finish after just `n` elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Combine it’s called `prefix(_:)`.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204737-prefix

Comment: Haha I missed that, thanks a lot! I guess I was expecting the names of the two methods `first` and `prefix` to be the same, as in RxSwift (`take`). But this makes sense, using the same naming as for e.g. arrays :)